# Get multiple values from form in html/php from an array and implode list values?

Tags: php

Not a php guru, trying to apply a multiple select on a dropdown within thsi code:

```
<?php if ( !empty( $categories ) ) : ?>
   <label for="<?php echo $widget_id; ?>-categories"><?php _e( 'find', 'GeoMashup' ); ?>
   <select multiple id="<?php echo $widget_id; ?>-categories" name="map_cat">
   <?php foreach ( $categories as $cat ) : ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>"<?php
        if ( $widget->get_default_value( $_POST, 'map_cat' ) == $cat->term_id )
            echo ' selected="selected"';
    ?>><?php echo $cat->name; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<?php _e( 'posts', 'GeoMashup' ); ?></label>
```

Currently even if I added `multiple` in the html select, the results I get is only for 1 select as if it is not recognizing the multiple selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `[]` to the name of the select element. Unless you do that, you'll only receive the last element (as you've noticed). You'll receive an array with [].

`<select multiple id="<?php echo $widget_id; ?>-categories" name="map_cat[]">`

Comment: i get: Warning: preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in

Comment: Yes, because you'll receive an array, not a string. That's even written in my answer.

Comment: i see, and how do i get the values from the array afterwards?

Comment: Loop through it or use implode() to make a string. http://ch2.php.net/implode

Comment: But actually preg_split() does make an array from a string, so you don't need to use preg_split, because you already have an array.

Comment: so I should do:
$array = map_cat[];
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array); - echo $comma_separated;

Comment: `$array = $_POST['map-cat'];`

Comment: if I do: 
$array = map_cat[]; 
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array); 
and then <select multiple id="<?php echo $widget_id; ?>-categories" name="<?php echo $comma_separated; ?>"> I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: Yes, because your wrong line is `$array = map_cat[];` This is not correct. map_cat[] is nothing. You have to access your form inputs over $_GET or $_POST (depends on the method you've used for the form). So it'd be `$array = $_POST['map_cat']; $comma_separated = implode(",", $array); - echo $comma_separated; `. Yes, no []. Since [] was only used to tell the browser to send it manufactured as array.

Comment: ok it does work as a form using multiple selection, however I am having this error msg at the top even tho it works Warning: implode() [function.implode]:

Comment: ok done, I had to define it as an array here $comma_separated = implode(",", (array)$array);